# Populate text area when dropdown item is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, google-cloud-datastore

I am quite new in coding. Let me come directly to the question. I have a dropdown in my jsp which gets populated with the entity kinds from the datastore(JDO) when the page is loaded. This is what I want. When I select an entity kind from the dropdown, a text area should populate with the column names of that particular entity kind. It can be in javascript or jQuery. Pls help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this is what you are looking for?

```
<div>
    <textarea id="carPark"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
    <select id="carDealer">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
</div>

function putIt(e) {
    $("#carPark").val(e.target.value);
}

$("#carDealer").on("change", putIt);
```

It's on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/YEcye/) for you to play with